# Unit test Javascript Ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, unit-testing

I want to test an Ajax call in vanilla Javascript and not using any Unit test framework. I was thinking to create an:

```
assert function
```

where to compare the result of the ajax call with the expected result.
Is this reasonable or I should test something more?

Comment: why do you want to test the server's code from js? why don't you do it server side?

Comment: you are right, I did not think about it

Comment: This is no longer a unit test, but an integrations test since it already involves two separate systems. If you want to continue unit testing the JS, you should mock out the network portion (i.e. abstract away the network calls, have it return fake responses).

Comment: @Joseph and what should I assert?

Comment: If you're calling a function that *you wrote*, you test that function's return value given a fixed network response. If that function isn't code you wrote (i.e. a library function), you don't need to test that.